# Filter object with keys in array

Tags: javascript

I have this array

```
const array = [1, 3, 6];
```

and this object

```
const obj = {
   1: {id: 1, foo: 'a', ...},
   2: {id: 2, foo: 'b', ...}
   3: {id: 3, foo: 'c', ...},
   4: {id: 4, foo: 'd', ...},
   5: {...},
   6: {...}
   ... // up to 1000 key/value paris
};
```

I wonder how to filter the `obj` with the keys in the `array`.
One way would be

```
obj.filter(elem => elem.id...);
```

But that iterates through all the elements in the `obj`, eventhough there are just three elements in the `array`.
Better would be to iterate over the `array`, but

```
array.filter(elem => elem === obj.id ...);
```

then only returns the elements from the `array`(meaning, `1, 3, 6`). 
What I need is an array looking like

```
const result  = ['s', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
```

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: What is the logic behind the `result  = ['foo', 'bar']`?

Comment: does the data have the `id` as key?

Comment: @NikhilAggarwal what do you mean with that?

Comment: @NinaScholz Yes the `id` is the `key`,

Comment: I mean what are these values `foo` and `bar`? Additionally, will there be any values in the array that does not exist in the `obj`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can map over the array and and return the key foo from within the object

```
const res = array.map(elem => obj[elem].foo);
```

If all elements don't exists in the object you can add a filter condition to remove undefined values

```
const res = array.map(elem => obj[elem] &&obj[elem].foo).filter(Boolean);
```

Comment: Provided all `array` elements actually exist in `obj`.

Comment: @georg, yes you are right. I updated the answer to take care of the undefined case too

Answer (score 4):

If you have the `id` as key, you could map the wanted values by filtering the keys for getting only known key and then map the value.

```js
const
    array = [1, 3, 6],
    object = { 1: { id: 1, foo: 'bar' }, 2: {}, 3: { id: 3, foo: 'foo' }, 4: {}, 5: {} },
    result = array 
        .filter(Object.hasOwnProperty.bind(object))
        .map(id => object[id].foo);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

If all the values in `array` exist in `obj` then use [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) else if there are missing entries in `obj` then can use [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```js
const array = [1, 3, 6];
const obj = {1: {id: 1, foo: 'bar'},2: {id: 2, foo: 'foo'}};
 
const result = array.reduce((a,c) => obj[c] ? a.concat(obj[c].foo) : a, []);;
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to iterate all the objects you just need to check whether the key is exist or not, if the key is exists you push the foo value to the result array
Here's the code :

```
const array = [1, 3, 6];

const obj = {
    1: {id: 1, foo: 'bar'},
    2: {id: 2, foo: 'foo'},
    3: {},
    4: {},
    5: {},
    6: {}
};

let result = [];

array.forEach((el) => {
    if(obj.hasOwnProperty(el)){
        result.push(obj[el].foo)
    }
});

console.log(result);
```